# Google Line Chart show date range even with 'null' values

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Im having some issues figuring out how to have my Google Line Chart displaying the given date range in its data array, when it all contains null values from a given point.

I have specified data for 1 month, but I only got data up until 2th December. This causes the chart to automatically zoom its view from 12th November up until that date, and truncate the 10 last days.

This is my data:

[image]

And this is the chart as it is being displayed:

[image]

I could however change the null values to 0, but that would make the lines flatline for the rest of the days, and thats not optimal. However, I do want to visualize to the user, that there are no recorded data for those last 10 days.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I have set interpolateNulls to true, and that does fix the gap between the lines where data is missing, but unfortunately, it does not show the remaining 10 days since there is no data there for it to connect the lines to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to fill the gaps from `null` values,
set option:

```
interpolateNulls: true
```

to set a specific date range on the x-axis,
use option:

```
hAxis: {
  viewWindow: {
    min: beginDate,
    max: endDate
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2017, 11, 5), 3],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 6), 4],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 7), 4],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 8), 3],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 9), null],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 10), 4],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 11), null],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 12), 4]
  ]);

  var options = {
    interpolateNulls: true,
    hAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        max: new Date(2017, 11, 31)
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div')
  );
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the interpolateNulls is already set to true (except from in my screenshot). The issue is, if lets say the 10, 11 and 12th of november in your example was null as well. Then it wouldn't interpolate to anything, and the graph will zoom in on only the existing data.

Comment: But then again, I see that I have to resort to the min and max values. Was hoping I could avoid that part in a dynamic scenario. However, seems like the only solution since Ive been up and down the documentations for line charts, so thanks :)